# TS - Loop through Array of Objects & add to a new array if not found

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, typescript, object

I am being provided an array of the following objects:

```
export interface Part {
  workOrder?: string;
  task?: string;
  partNumber?: string;
  qty?: number;
  image?: string;
  name?: string;
}
```

I want to be able to loop through each of those & create a new array from the following `interface`:

```
export interface WorkOrder {
  workOrder?: string;
  tasks?: Array<string>;
}
```

Here's what my code looks like

```
let partList: Part[] = [ 
  { workOrder: "W1", task: "do something", ... },
  { workOrder: "W1", task: "something else", ... },
  { workOrder: "W2", task: "do something", ... },
  { workOrder: "W2", task: "something else", ... }
];

let workOrders: WorkOrder[] = [];
```

I want to be able to add workOrder & task from each Part into the `workOrders` array, but if W1 has already been added, then I need it to add the second task "something else" to the tasks array from the W1 object.

**The end result should look like this:**

```
workOrders = [ 
  { workOrder: "W1", tasks: [ "do something", "something else" ] },
  { workOrder: "W2", tasks: [ "do something", "something else" ] }
];
```

I almost have it working with a few for loops and checking the `.indexOf()` for certain arrays, but I feel like there is probably a better way.

Comment: Is the order of the output array significant?

Comment: No. I don't care about the order at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
partList.forEach(elm => {
  if (!workOrders.find(wo => wo.workOrder == elm.workOrder)) {
      workOrders.push({ workOrder: elm.workOrder, tasks: new Array(elm.task) 
  });
  } else {
      workOrders.find(wo => wo.workOrder == 
      elm.workOrder).tasks.push(elm.task);
  }
})
```

You can use find method to find if element is added, if it's added then push to tasks or create new work order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` function.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
let partList = [
  { workOrder: "W1", task: "do something" },
  { workOrder: "W1", task: "something else" },
  { workOrder: "W2", task: "do something" },
  { workOrder: "W2", task: "something else" },
  { workOrder: "W3", task: "something else Three (3)" }
];

let workOrders = partList.reduce((a, c) => {
  var current = a.find((e) => e.workOrder === c.workOrder);
  if (current)
    current.tasks.push(c.task);
  else
    a.push({ workOrder: c.workOrder, tasks: [c.task]});
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(workOrders);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

## Resources

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I would worry about the performance of `find` if there are a lot of groups. Also why not just `a.push`, why create a new array on each iteration ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you for the observation.  a) certainly that `find` will affect the performance for big groups.  b) you're totally right, that new Array is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method to create an object that contains the data by `workOrder` :

```
var result = partList
    .reduce<{ [name: string]: WorkOrder }>((map, r) => {
        let extsing = map[r.workOrder];
        if (extsing) {
            extsing.tasks.push(r.task);
        } else {
            map[r.workOrder] = {
                tasks: [r.task],
                workOrder: r.workOrder
            };
        }
        return map;
    }, {});

var asArray = Object.values(result)
```

If you use grouping often, you could create a `group` function to help with this task:

```
function group<T>(data: T[]) {
    return {
        byKey(keyGetter: (e: T) => string) {
            return {
                createGroup<TResult>(ctor: (e: T) => TResult) {
                    return {
                        addToGroup(adder: (e: T, c: TResult) => void) {
                            var result = data
                                .reduce<{ [name: string]: TResult }>((map, r) => {
                                    let key = keyGetter(r)
                                    let extsing = map[key];
                                    if (extsing) {
                                        adder(r, extsing);
                                    } else {
                                        map[key] = ctor(r);
                                    }
                                    return map;
                                }, {});

                            return Object.values(result)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
let result = group(partList)
    .byKey(x => x.workOrder)
    .createGroup(x => <WorkOrder>{ tasks: [x.task], workOrder: x.workOrder })
    .addToGroup((e, c) => c.tasks.push(e.task));
```